# Conformance issues even after fulfilling requirements using protocol extensions for @objc protocols

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

Let us consider this example which compiles without any issues :

```
protocol AProtocol {
    func veryImportantMethod()
}

protocol BProtocol : AProtocol {

}

extension BProtocol {
    func veryImportantMethod() {
        print("A's protocol requirement satisfied!")
    }
}

class ConcreteClass : BProtocol {

}
```

However, if we do this :

```
@objc protocol AProtocol { //Added @objc here
    func veryImportantMethod()
}

protocol BProtocol : AProtocol {

}

extension BProtocol {
    func veryImportantMethod() {
        print("A's protocol requirement satisfied!")
    }
}

class ConcreteClass :  BProtocol {

}
```

It doesn't compile with a message saying :

> Type 'ConcreteClass' does not conform to protocol 'AProtocol'

However, if we actually implement it,

```
class ConcreteClass : NSObject, BProtocol {
    func veryImportantMethod() { }
}
```

the code compiles. Why is this happening? Is there anything that I am missing here?

I am trying to achieve this form of protocol hierarchy for `UITableViewDataSource` and I really do not want to repeat `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code across conformants.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler wants to make sure that the class can be compiled with ObjC. Once you inherit from an ObjC class (like `NSObject`) the compiler knows it, but you implement the extension before that point. You could avoid the error by defining the protocol to be implemented by a class that inherits from `NSObject`, like this:

```
@objc protocol AProtocol {
    func veryImportantMethod()
}

protocol BProtocol : AProtocol {

}

class BProtocolClass: NSObject {

}

extension BProtocolClass {
    func veryImportantMethod() {
        print("A's protocol requirement satisfied!")
    }
}

class ConcreteClass: BProtocolClass {

}
```